# Restore an AWS db from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two different AWS servers for RDS instances.

I want to restore db from one server to another, but can't since the backup is created on another server(which it belongs to).

What is the best way to do this?
So far, I have created the backup and am trying to copy it in my local using scp command like this :

```
scp <username>@<servername>:"/D:/rdsdbdata/BACKUP/filename.bak" -U <username> -P <pass> "D:/"
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Amazon RDS databases use "instances", not "servers". What do you mean by "the backup is created on another server"? Are you referring to an Amazon RDS **Snapshot**?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes that's what I meant , we have to put servername while connecting  mssqlserver  to db , hence the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

To 'backup' an Amazon RDS database, you can **create a Snapshot**. This copies the complete contents of the database instance.

The snapshot is kept within the Amazon RDS service -- there is no need to download or save the snapshot.

You can then **launch a new Amazon RDS instance from the snapshot**. The new RDS instance will contain all data that was saved in the Snapshot. Please note that you must **create a new RDS instance** from the snapshot -- you do not copy or load the data into an existing RDS instance.

See: [Working with backups - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply , I currently don't have access to console or cli . I currently have server name (which is of the format : .........ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com) of the sql server instance and its credentials .
Is it possible ?

Comment: To use the RDS Snapshot capability, you will need access credentials to the AWS Account. Without such access, all you can do is send SQL commands. I couldn't find documentation explaining how to copy to/from the `rdsdbdata` directory on an RDS database.